# API call returning error while using CURL in php

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am calling a web service at 
http://test.dnb.avantimedns.se/drombolig/webservices/autoprospectservice.asmx?op=SaveAutoprospect

API KEY: de2de92-5d8c-4dcc-8573-9354b96ba683
OBJECT ID: 90160211

but it is not returning valid response. Below is my code. Kindly help in fixing.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "http://test.dnb.avantimedns.se/drombolig/webservices/autoprospectservice.asmx?op=SaveAutoprospect",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{\n \"autoprospect\": \"{\\"SendAdditionalProspects\\":false,\\"RequestsEconomicalAdvice\\":false,\\"RequestsAssessment\\":false,\\"UserEmailsuccess\\":true,\\"ApprovesContact\\":true,\\"ObjectId\\":\\"90160211\\",\\"Source\\":\\"Company\\",\\"Name\\":\\"Test Testsson\\",\\"Email\\":\\"test@test.com\\",\\"ZipCode\\":\\"12345\\",\\"Phone\\":\\"1234567890\\",\\"Message\\":\\"Test\\"}\",\n \"apikey\": \"de2de92-5d8c-4dcc-8573-9354b96ba683\"\n \n}',

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("content-type: application/json"),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it returns valid response (in my case it returns exception and stack). The issue seems to be on api call side.

The response is looking like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  ▶
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)\r\n
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)\r\n
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()\r\n
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()\r\n
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()\r\n
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()\r\n
       at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)\r\n
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortP ▶
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Comment: Thanks for reply Alexxx. However API team claims that everything is fine at their end.

Comment: try to change `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",` to `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",`  its working for me

Comment: I tried but it is now displaying the whole page http://test.dnb.avantimedns.se/drombolig/webservices/autoprospectservice.asmx?op=SaveAutoprospect instead of response

Comment: hmm.. looks like issues in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS field. Especially autoprospect property isn't proper. Anyway response is successful if you send curl without any CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS options